# dplyr conditional mutate with ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I want to make this statement more generic

```
mutate(across(
  Kingdom:Genus,
  ~ ifelse(.x == "Incertae sedis", "*Incertae sedis*", .x)
))
```

how can I indicate "* Incertae sedis *" in a more general way? basically I want to add an asterisk at the beginning and at the end of the string in .x

Comment: I can think of several reasons why you likely wouldn't want to use a math symbol, or 'any possible symbol' in the regex sense, to generalize, imagining a future search, as yet unanticipated, for the same entry. Perhaps `nomem dubium`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to insert the `*` with a regex

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   mutate(across(Kingdom:Genus,  ~str_replace(.x, "(Incertae sedis)", "*\\1*")))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `paste0`:

```r
mutate(across(
  Kingdom:Genus,
  ~ ifelse(.x == "Incertae sedis", paste0("*", .x, "*"), .x)
))
```

If you have multiple terms that you want to highlight, you could define them in a vector first and use this instead:

```r
uncertain <- c("Incertae sedis", "Problematica", "Nomem Dubium")

df %>% mutate(across(
  Kingdom:Genus,
  ~ ifelse(.x %in% uncertain, paste0("*", .x, "*"), .x)
))
```

Answer (score 2):

Cave this is experimental:
The answer by @Allan Cameron is best with `paste0`

But I would like to share this: **`str_pad`**

```
# fake dataframe
df <- tribble(
  ~A, ~B, ~C,
  "Incertae sedis", "blabla", "Incertae sedis",
  "Incertae sedis",  "blabla", "bloblo",
  "Incertae", "Incertae sedis", "blibli"
)

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(A:C, ~ifelse(. == "Incertae sedis", str_pad(., nchar(.)+2, "both", pad="*"), .)))
```

```
 A                B                C               
  <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
1 *Incertae sedis* blabla           *Incertae sedis*
2 *Incertae sedis* blabla           bloblo          
3 Incertae         *Incertae sedis* blibli
```